# Discord bot only gives role to me

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make my discord bot mass give everyone in my server a role. Whenever I do `-giveall` it only gives me the role. I have tried using map and array. Using      `message.guild.members.filter(member => member.roles.array().length > 1).forEach(member => member.addRole(role));` with no luck.

```
if (command === 'giveall') {
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == 'cool')

if (!role) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, role not found`)
    message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => !m.user.bot).forEach(member => member.roles.add(role))
message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, role **${role.name}** was added to all members`)
  }
```

Comment: Have you enabled Member Intents in your Discord API?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the log I received with `console.log(message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => !m.user.bot));`:

```js
Collection [Map] {
  '759457326251114536' => GuildMember {
    guild: Guild {
      members: [GuildMemberManager],
      channels: [GuildChannelManager],
      roles: [RoleManager],
      presences: [PresenceManager],
      voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
      deleted: false,
      available: true,
      id: '760015259619819550',
      shardID: 0,
      name: 'GoodGameBTW™',
      icon: '5c364ec985a0706a27c31b89953d01e4',
      splash: null,
      discoverySplash: null,
      region: 'india',
      memberCount: 10,
      large: false,
      features: [Array],
      applicationID: null,
      afkTimeout: 300,
      afkChannelID: null,
      systemChannelID: null,
      embedEnabled: undefined,
      premiumTier: 0,
      premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
      verificationLevel: 'LOW',
      explicitContentFilter: 'ALL_MEMBERS',
      mfaLevel: 0,
      joinedTimestamp: 1603042420216,
      defaultMessageNotifications: 'MENTIONS',
      systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
      maximumMembers: 100000,
      vanityURLCode: null,
      vanityURLUses: null,
      description: null,
      banner: null,
      rulesChannelID: '771729349632196608',
      publicUpdatesChannelID: '768502471676788777',
      preferredLocale: 'en-US',
      ownerID: '759457326251114536',
      emojis: [GuildEmojiManager]
    },
    joinedTimestamp: 1601272158336,
    lastMessageID: '773102408938029056',
    lastMessageChannelID: '760778837612822558',
    premiumSinceTimestamp: 0,
    deleted: false,
    nickname: null,
    _roles: [ '760763514402111488', '760759896232296468' ],
    user: User {
      id: '759457326251114536',
      username: 'Prof. MineKraft',
      bot: false,
      discriminator: '6612',
      avatar: '97ee817e5098d3e6ee4c174a449d1779',
      flags: [UserFlags],
      lastMessageID: '773102408938029056',
      lastMessageChannelID: '760778837612822558'
    }
  }
}
```

From the log, you can see that the cache has only two users, the bot and you. So when you filter the bot out, only you get the role.

This can be because you have gateway intents disabled. Please go to the discord developer portal and enable the Server member intent. That should fix your problem.

Comment: The code that you gave me was  from v11. I  had converted it to  `const list = client.guilds.cache.get("guildid")` and `list.members.cache.forEach(member => member.roles.add(role)); ` so it can be migrated to v12,  and it still only gives me the role.

Comment: Sorry Sir but he has used `member.roles.add(Role_id)` only. Please look again.

Comment: `forEach()` is an array method, and `guild.members.cache` is a discord collection.

Comment: Opps, sorry then. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Yup  I  just needed to enable PRESENCE INTENT and SERVER MEMBERS INTENT for it to work, thanks!

Comment: @Flappy Happy to help!